# Typed.js does not work for multiple instances

Tags: html, typed.js

```
    var options = {
        typeSpeed: 30,
        showCursor: false,
        cursorChar: "|",
        loop: true,
        backSpeed: 30,
        backDelay: 5000,
        startDelay: 10
    };

    var typed1 = new Typed("#demoz1", {
        strings: ["Innovative And Reliable Technologies"],
        ...options
    });
    var typed2 = new Typed("#demoz2", {
        strings: ["Profitable Software Tailored To Your Business"],
        ...options
    });
```

The first works but the second does not.Is this a bug with Typed.js? I notcied once i instantiate a second time it does not work.How am i supposed to achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem, some libraries above typed.js prevented it from running.